# Is it possible to apply a plugin from another SubProject/Module in Gradle without Publishing?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a project with the following **SubProjects/Modules**

```
Project
  |
  +----gradle-plugin
  |
  +----sample-module-to-test-the-plugin
```

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            maven {
                url "https://jitpack.io"
                credentials { username 'my-secret-token-for-private-repo' }
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            // classpath project(':plugin') <-- invalid syntax
            classpath "com.github.my-repo:my-gradle-plugin:0.1.9"
        }
    }
    apply "my-custom-plugin-id"
```

The problem is that I have to comment out the lines above then publish to local maven or even to the remote one before I can apply the plugin,

**Q: Is there a way to have a local classpath dependency like in normal dependencies? where we specify it as**

```
implementation project(':module-name')
```